# What happens if you delete a file in PHP while the web server is serving the file to the website visitor

Tags: php, filesystems, unlink

```
unlink("cache/data.xml");
```

I feel that this may generate an error at times when sever might be reading and serving it to the visitor.

how to safely delete the file so script will continue to wait until the read lock from the web server is released if any and then continue deleting the file or how it works out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will depend on the specific system this is running on, but the man page for the UNIX `unlink` function (which the PHP `unlink` function very likely relies on internally) says this:

> The `unlink()` function removes the link named by path from its
>   directory  and decrements the link count of the file which was
>   referenced by the  link.  If that decrement reduces the link count of
>   the file to zero, and  no process has the file open, then all
>   resources associated with the file  are reclaimed.  If one or more
>   process have the file open when the last  link is removed, the link is
>   removed, but the removal of the file is  delayed until all references
>   to it have been closed.

In other words, the process reading the file can continue to do so, even while the file is being deleted.

Comment: so what about if the file is modified while being served?